# Rails Routing Error for nested form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I now this has been asked a thousand times but that doesn't help me heh :) I've been at this an hour.  My form:

```
= form_for @comment, :url_for => { :action => "create", :controller => "comments"}, :method => :post
```

my rake routes:

```
                   POST   /t/:trunk_id/r/:root_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
trunk_root_comment GET    /t/:trunk_id/r/:root_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
```

The error:

```
undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fed2c713128>:0x007fed2c71cc78>
```

If I name space the form to:

```
= form_for [:trunk_root, @comment], :url_for => { :action => "create", :controller => "comments"}, :method => :post do |f|
```

which should make the route trunk_root_comments_path.. which is correct according to the rake routes.. I get:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :format=>nil}
```

Help is very much appreciated.. been looking at this for hours..

UPDATE:

Thank you Ryan for such a great answer! A very clear explanation of something I was just sort of 'throwing things' at, now at least I understand better. I actually already had 'trunk_root_comments_path' available in my rake routes, and I had tried a couple of the combinations you mentioned, but I wasn't really grocking what I was missing, so you helped.  I'm using Mongo and I don't actually have a Trunk model, I just have an attribute on roots called @root.trunk, though I have a trunk controller and therefore its a part of my routes(maybe a bad idea idk).

So I tried your TLDR and it said error:

```
Undefined method 'root_comments_path'
```

.. cause no Trunk model exists, I assume?.. so I made @trunk just equal the correct id with

```
= form_for [@trunk, @root, @comment] do |f|
```

<- and I got 'undefined method `politics_root_comments_path''.. I figured well.. that probably makes sense.. since I'm failing I must as well try your most explicit version:

```
= form_for @comment, :url => (trunk_root_comments_path(:trunk_id => @root.trunk, :root_id => @root.id)) do |f|
```

and sure enough that worked... so I'm not quite sure how to do it shorter then this.. the odd thing for me is I have another nested resource "photos" at the same level of depth in the routes and I was able to get that to work with = form_for [:trunk_root, @photo], :html => { :class => 'root_form' } do |f|.. but here for some reason I couldn't.. anyways I'd say you gave me enough to understand 100% but I think I went from 20% understanding to 50% understanding.. I know now that id's ARE important to routes, and the named helpers need access to them.  I got an introduction to how the url_helper works, but would need to read more on it to really grock it fully I think.  I'm also now able to construct proper routes in their longer form at least to get through tricky situations like this.  So thank you :)

Comment: Ignore my answer (at least for a while :)) How are your routes set up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR You need to specify both a `:trunk_id` and a `root_id` in your URL or use `form_for` like this:

```
<%= form_for [@trunk, @root, @comment] do |f| %>
```

Rails is attempting to build a URL from the hash you're giving it, but that hash doesn't match anything in its routing table. You could do this:

```
{ :controller => "comments", :action => "create", :trunk_id => trunk.id, :root_id => root.id }
```

But that's really a bit *tl;dr*.

The cooler way to do it is this:

```
trunk_root_comments_path(trunk, root)
```

Where `trunk` and `root` are `Trunk` and `Root` instances respectively.

Now, if you want to be *super-wicked-cool*, do it like this:

```
<%= form_for [trunk, root, comment] do |f| %>
```

Science!

**So how does this work? Elementary, my dear:**

Rails first recognises that we're using `form_for` using an Array and that *we mean business*. Rails uses this array passed in and builds a URL out of it. It does this by using the routing helpers that are defined by the routes. Unfortunately, you've defined your routes in a funny way that don't play nice with this, but *don't fear!* We can fix this.

The way you can do it is this where you have this in `config/routes.rb`:

```
post '/t/:trunk_id/r/:root_id/comments'
```

Instead put this:

```
post '/t/:trunk_id/r/:root_id/comments', :as => "trunk_root_comments"
```

You may *alternatively* already have this:

```
match '/t/:trunk_id/r/:root_id/comments', :via => :post
```

Which should become this:

```
match '/t/:trunk_id/r/:root_id/comments', :via => :post, :as => "trunk_root_comments"
```

Either way, you've now got *not one, but **two(!!)*** path helpers defined by the routes. These are`trunk_root_comments_path` and `trunk_root_comments_url` respectively. **The names of these methods are super important for what I am about to explain to you. Pay attention!**

So, back to our little `form_for` call:

```
<%= form_for [trunk, root, comment] do |f| %>
```

Rails knows that we're using an Array because it can see it. What it does with this Array may *seem* like magic, but isn't really.

Rails will take each element of this array and build a routing helper method *name* up from the different parts. This isn't actually part of `form_for`, but another method called `url_for` that you can use by itself:

```
 url_for([trunk, root, comment])
```

In the beginning, this routing helper method name generated by `url_for` is simply an empty array (`[]`). Nothing special at all.

But then what happens *is* special!

The first element is going to be a *persisted instance* of the `Trunk` class. By "persisted" I mean that it's an object that maps *directly* to a record in the database. Yay ORMs!

Rails will know this, and so will turn the routing helper into this: `[:trunk]`.

The second element is going to be a *persisted instance* of the `Root` class. Rails also knows this (damn, Rails is *smart*!) and will then append this to the array, turning it into `[:trunk, :root]`. Awesome.

The third (and final) element is then checked by Rails. It sees that (in this case) it's a non-persisted element, i.e. it's not been saved to the database.. yet. Rails treats this differently and will instead append `[:comments]` to the array, turning it into this:

```
[:trunk, :root, :comments]
```

See where I'm going with this now?

Now that Rails has done it's thing (or *thang*, if you like) it will join these three parts together like this: `trunk_root_comments`, and just for good measure it'll put `_path` on the end of it, turning it into the final `trunk_root_comments_path` helper.

And then! Man, and then... Rails calls this method and passes it arguments! Just like this:

```
trunk_root_comments_path(:trunk_id => trunk.id, :root_id => root_id)
```

This generates a full path to the resource like this:

```
/t/:trunk_id/r/:root_id/comments
```

And *bam!* Full circle! That's how Rails will know to generate the URL and you don't have to use ugly hashes anymore.

Success!

Comment: Thanks Ryan! What a great answer.  Hope more people having routing issues see this.  Got it working, though maybe not as tldr as I'd like but you can see my update for details.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have this route set up but try:

```
= form_for @comment, :url => trunk_root_comments_path
```

Comment: Won't work, route needs both `:trunk_id` and `:root_id` parameters passed in or available on the request where this form is being rendered.

Comment: Thanks jlundqvist for the response.  I updated my answer above to reflect how I got it working using one of Ryan Bigg's suggestions.